# Blazor app not maintainintg its state on IIS, but works fine on IISExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an issue where I am trying to obtain the context userID and display it. This works great on IISExpress from within VS but has an issue on IIS.

When the page first loads, it displays the username properly. Then a second later it shows the "not authorized" message. I am assuming this is an issue with pre-render/postback of some kind that doesn't happen in VS, but I'm at a loss as to what is causing this. :

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync
@inject Data.LoginState loginState

<PageTitle>Tools</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            @if (loginState.IsLoggedIn.Equals(false))
            {
                <h5>You are not authorized</h5>
            }
            else{
                <h5>Welcome: @loginState.username</h5>
            }
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @if (loginState.IsLoggedIn.Equals(false)){}
            @Body

        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code{
    string? username = String.Empty;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {        
        try
        {
            username = (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Substring(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            loginState.SetLoginAsync(true, username);
        }
    }
}
```

LoginState is in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginState>();
```

This is using Windows Authentication

Also I get the standard:

> Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets

even with the appsettings.config entry line

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. It requires Windows feature Web Sockets to be installed and then suddenly pre-render or whatever was causing it no longer breaks the functionality.

[Web Sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIz8L.png)